# while loop does not work and ends regardless of != or ==

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to write my first Python program (text-based adventure) and I am having some trouble with getting my loop to work. What should I do to ask the user what their name is and to confirm Y/y again if their response is != Y or y?

```py
def askName():

    print("What is your name?")

askName()

charName = input()

def confirmName():

    print("Is your name " + charName + "? Enter Y for YES or N for NO.")

confirmName()

yesorno = input()

while yesorno != "Y" or yesorno != "y":

    confirmName()
    yesorno = input()
    if yesorno == "Y" or yesorno == "y":
        break

print("Welcome " + charName + "!")
```

Comment: I think you forgot to ask the name again inside the loop. Add one else block to the if branch and ask the name again. That should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly , this is how it should look.

```
    print("What is your name?")
name = input()

while len(yesorno) == 0:
    yesorno = input()
if yesorno == "Y" or yesorno == "y":
    < do something........ >
else:
    name = input()
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! It works but I would like 
print("What is your name?") 
name = input()
confirmName()
yesorno = input()
to loop over and over again (while) until the user finally responds with yesorno == "Y" or yesorno =="y".

(Sorry I am still figuring out how to use this site so the formatting is a little whack)

Comment: Try above , i have added the loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
def askName():
    print("What is your name?")
    charName = input()
    confirmName(charName)
def confirmName(charName):
    print("Is your name " + charName + "? Enter Y for YES or N for NO.")
    yesorno = input()
    if yesorno == "Y" or yesorno == "y":
        print("Welcome " + charName + "!")
    else:
        askName()
askName()
```

It will keep asking user about name until "y" or "Y" key is pressed.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you! I didn't realize I could def multiple lines. A question: why does this continue to ask until y/Y is pressed even though it is not a while loop?

Comment: @strugglingstudent In the code, for if-else condition, I am calling askName() function again and again in the "else" condition until "if" condition is true i.e., until y/Y key is pressed.